# iterate through json matrix php android

Tags: php, android, json, matrix

Hi I have a script here

http://myprocity.com/android/fetchthecity.php

That returns a array of arrays. I want to parse through this in Android and store each value.

The code I have right now is this, maybe this is flawed? I'm getting nothing to show up

```
public static void refreshFeed(Activity act){

    ActionEngine.swamiOn = false;

    FetchTheCityTask f = new FetchTheCityTask(act);
    f.execute();

    try {

        if (f.get() != null) {

            JSONArray feedArr = new JSONArray();
            feedArr = json.getJSONArray("data");
            ArrayList<UserRecord> items = new ArrayList<UserRecord>();

            for(int i = 0; i < feedArr.length(); i++){

                for(int j = 0; j < feedArr.getJSONArray(i).length(); j++) {

                    JSONObject row = feedArr.getJSONArray(i).getJSONObject(j);
                    String item = row.getString("Item");
                    String descp = row.getString("Description");
                    String pic = row.getString("PicPath");
                    String time = row.getString("Time");
                    String donatedby = row.getString("DonatedBy");
                    String ebase = row.getString("Ebase");
                    String cond = row.getString("Condition");
                    String loc = row.getString("Location");

                    items.add(new UserRecord(item,descp,pic,time,donatedby,
                            ebase,cond,loc));

                }
            }

            TheCityFragment.feedArea.setAdapter(new UserItemAdapter(act,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
```

Answer (score 0):

> That returns a array of arrays.

I don't think so,

I see from your file "Array of Objects" so your code doesn't work.

[image]

Try to do something:

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(resultAsString);
// ...

for(int i=0;i<json.length();i++){ 
              //...
               JSONObject row = json.getJSONObject(j);
                String item = row.getString("Item");
                String descp = row.getString("Description");
                String pic = row.getString("PicPath");
                String time = row.getString("Time");
                String donatedby = row.getString("DonatedBy");
                String ebase = row.getString("Ebase");
                String cond = row.getString("Condition");
                String loc = row.getString("Location"); 
          //..         
}
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: hi Maxim, ok so I"m getting an Array of Objects, how do I parse through each one...um I'm stuck on the syntax should I be iterating through a JSONArray or JSONObject that is returned from json.getJSONArray("data");

Comment: see my example, you get `json.getJSONArray` from your string, and after run in loop

Comment: it gives me a type mismatch when I do this
    
JSONArray feedArr = new JSONArray(f.get());

Comment: f.get() is the toString of this whole thing

Comment: try 1st `getJSONObject(f.get())` and after fetch array from object. see my pic

Comment: still not working, I'm returning from echo json_encode($data); an array of objects, how do I parse this properly

Comment: getting this as a string is typemismatching in JSONArray

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON result, parsed on : http://bodurov.com/jsonformatter/ shows this result :

[image: JSON Result]

I'd recommend to change the json result to this one :

```
{"data" : [yourjsonArray]}
```

So you need to encapsulate the `JSON_ARRAY` inside a `JSON_OBJECT`, so you can use `getJSONArray("data")` to get the array.

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(resultstringhere); //f.get() ?
JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("data");
```

Hope this helps,

Reid